# how to deploy war and run with docker

Tags: docker

I have a Spring MVC project, which will generate a war of size 90 MB. Currently, I am manually copying the war to tomcat web apps and starting the server.
Now I want to deploy that war with docker?

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM tomcat:8.0
ADD tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
EXPOSE 8080
RUN rm -fr /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
RUN rm -fr /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
COPY ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I am building my image with

```
docker build -t webserver .
```

staring the container with

```
docker run -d  -p 8080:8080  --name mydockerapp webserver
```

after container starting successfully, I am trying to access `localhost:8080/mydockerapp`, which is not working.

please help.

Comment: Run `docker logs your_containers_id` and post the result to your OP. Also validate that the context path of your application is correct.

Comment: `docker ps` to confirm your container still alive, and enter you container to see if your process ok in container, `ps aux`. More, check tomcat log in container just like you do on physical machine.

Comment: For debug purposes start the the docker container with it attached to the terminal, thus using `-t` instead of `-d`, eg: `docker run -t  -p 8080:8080  --name mydockerapp webserver`. The output should tell what is wrong.